# SQLite escape method

Tags: c#, sqlite

I wonder if there's any possibility of finding a function that escapes all the invalid characters for `SQLite` query.

I have found out that in `Java` it can be done.

```
query = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_URL
                    }, 
                    "some'strange\"text in __________ here", 
                    variable,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
```

Do you know if you can do anything similar in `C#`?

Comment: Yes, using SQL parameters. It depends which connector you're using anyway ICommand object has a Parameters collection. A parameter can have any sequence of characters (no need to escape them) because it won't be _injected_ raw in SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQLite this is accomplished by using SQL parameters, there are various [formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) but generally `?` is enough i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X = ?
```

Then you pass the relevant parameter(s) using whichever mechanism your preferred driver provides. SQLite will internally take care of sanatizing the data.

Comment: I use `System.Data.SQLite` but I can find out how to do it as u said

Comment: If you are using `System.Data.SQLite` then the `?` parameter identifier doesn't matter too much as you can specify the parameter names when providing the parameters - here's an [example](http://snipplr.com/view/29247/)